# Restore Windows Server 2008 R2 from a Windows Server Backup (.vhd)

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a crashed (BSOD) Windows Server 2008 where i luckily have a backup from the night before the crash. This backup was made by using Windows Server Backup, doing a full system backup on a NAS. This creates a backup as 2 large .vhd files and some other small files in \192.168.56.14\administrator\WindowsBackupImages\Server1\date.
When I boot up the server I can do f8 and go to system repair and get the Windows System Recovery tool. Since the backup is not on the machine, but an external harddrive, it is expected the backup is not found. I've then tried to copy the backup to an external USB harddrive, attach it to the computer, with no luck, and also specify the network location in the recorvery tool. When using the network location I'm prompted for username and password, so I'm sure the NAS is found. I would expect the backup is being listed, but nothing is on the list in any of the cases.
What am I missing or doing wrong?
Really appreciate the help.
- Soren

Comment: IF you have a BSOD you should diagnose the BSOD before you restore, otherwise you run the risk of restoring to a system that will simply die again

Answer (score 1):

You can start system with Windows Server Installation DVD , choose restore a Backup and select the backup image on the NAS .

Comment: I think the OP is saying the he's tried that.

Comment: Yes, apperantly windows recovery needs to be startet from the cd and not by f8. Got it working. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Having been through this very thing myself recently I can tell you to try 3 things:

1. Make sure you have a DHCP server set up on the network. When trying to restore Windows from a backup located on a network drive, Windows (of course) needs TCP/IP connectivity in order to access the network and will need an ip address and subnet mask on the same network where the backup exists. In the repair/restore wizard you can bring up a command prompt (I don't remember the actual screen or option where this is available) and run ipconfig to confirm/verify that a valid TCP/IP configuration has been obtained.
2. After verifying a valid TCP\IP configuration, if prompted for credentials, use "anonymous" for the user name (without the quotes) with a blank password. This assumes that the NAS is running some Unix/Linux variant as it's OS.
3. When typing in the path to the backup make sure to type the full path to the WindowsImageBackup folder. Typing the path to the parent share is not enough as it appears that the backup routine will not traverse subfolders looking for a valid backup image.